# Cannot open link in emacs org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am trying to open a hyperlink inside emacs. Inside the org file, I tried to <kbd>C-c C-o</kbd> on the link, but instead of opening the link, emacs says "No match - create this  as a new heading? (y or n)"

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: From the org-mode manual on [internal links](http://orgmode.org/manual/Internal-links.html): "If the link does not look like a URL, it is considered to be internal in the current file." That's why org-mode asks you if you want to create a new heading if you don't format external links as described in Tobias' answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you missed the `http://` in front of the web-address?
A full link looks like that: `http://www.google.com` or that: `[[http://www.google.de]]` or that: `[[http://www.google.de][your description here]]`.

See <kbd>C-h i g (org) External links</kbd>.